# How to Modify Python Code in Order to Print Multiple Adjacent "Location" Tokens to Single Line of Output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to python, and I am trying to print all of the tokens that are identified as locations in an .xml file to a .txt file using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('exercise-ner.xml', 'r'))

tokenlist = soup.find_all('token')

output = ''

for x in tokenlist:

   readeachtoken = x.ner.encode_contents()

   checktoseeifthetokenisalocation = x.ner.encode_contents().find("LOCATION")

   if checktoseeifthetokenisalocation != -1:

   output += "\n%s" % x.word.encode_contents()

z = open('exercise-places.txt','w')

z.write(output)

z.close()
```

The program works, and spits out a list of all of the tokens that are locations, each of which is printed on its own line in the output file. What I would like to do, however, is to modify my program so that any time beautiful soup finds two or more adjacent tokens that are identified as locations, it can print those tokens to the same line in the output file. Does anyone know how I might modify my code to accomplish this? I would be entirely grateful for any suggestions you might be able to offer.

Comment: You should / could share your solution with us. Also, esp. if you're new to Python, take a look at PEP8 for guidance on style issues like naming your variables: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very old, but I just got your note @Amanda and I thought I'd post my approach to the task in case it might help others:

```
import glob, codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inside_location = 0
location_string = ''

with codecs.open("washington_locations.txt","w","utf-8") as out:
    for i in glob.glob("/afs/crc.nd.edu/user/d/dduhaime/java/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-29/processed_washington_correspondence/*.xml"):
        locations = []

        with codecs.open(i,'r','utf-8') as f:
            soup   = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
            tokens = soup.findAll('token')
            for token in tokens:
                if token.ner.string     == "LOCATION":
                    inside_location = 1
                    location_string += token.word.string + u" "
                else:
                    if location_string:
                        locations.append( location_string )
                        location_string = ''

        out.write( i + "\t" + "\t".join(l for l in locations) + "\n" )
```